# If div doesnt have a containing div with a certain class, do something. JQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, if-statement

If `#box` doesn't have a containing div with a class of `current-map`, then do something.

I thought the `!` would have worked but it doesn't.

```
if (!$('#box').closest('.current-map')) {

     //do something

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could check the length of the resulting selection. If it's `0`, there was no ancestor `.current-map` element:

```
if($("#box").closest(".current-map").length) {
    //.current-map is an ancestor
}
```

Your attempt does not work because most jQuery methods will return an instance of jQuery whether it contains any DOM elements or not, and that will always evaluate to `true`.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `:has()` selector instead. Turn the logic around.

```
if ( $('.current-map:has(#box)').length > 0 ) {
    // do backflips
}
```

`.closest()` is sort of notorious for being rather slow to work with.

Comment: If it's performance you're interested in then you should use the `.has` method rather than the selector so that `querySelectorAll` can be used for the selector in browsers that support it.

Answer (score 0):

Try .length in your if block

```
   if ($('#box').closest('.current-map').length > 0) {
      //do something
   }
```